# Three.js image disappearing after a few calls to requestAnimationFrame()

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webgl

I am trying to get some basic movement/refreshing working in Three.js. I've cut the problem back to the following code.

A sphere displays fine first render, and twice (dictate by Nb), but the image vanishes for 3 renders that are called via requestAnimationFrame(simulate) (for 4 it displays then disappears); Am I missing something in how repeated rendering should happen ?

```
var sphere, WIDTH, HEIGHT, VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR, renderer, camera, scene, sphereMaterial, radius, sphere, pointLight, container;

function init() {
  WIDTH = 400;
  HEIGHT = 300;
  VIEW_ANGLE = 45;
  ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
  NEAR = 0.1;
  FAR = 10000;

  container = $('#container');
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(  VIEW_ANGLE,
                              ASPECT,
                              NEAR,
                              FAR  );
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera.position.z = 200;
  renderer.setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
  container.append(renderer.domElement);
  sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
  {
      color: 0xCC0000
  });
  radius = 50; segments = 16; rings = 16;
  sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings),
    sphereMaterial);
  //sphere.position.z -= 100;
  scene.add(sphere);
  scene.add(camera);
  pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFFF );
  pointLight.position.x = 10;
  pointLight.position.y = 50;
  pointLight.position.z = 130;
  scene.add(pointLight);
};

var Nb = 3;
var j = 0; 

function simulate() {
  console.log("simulate " + sphere.position.z);
  if (j == Nb) { return; } 
  j++;
  //sphere.position.z -= 1;
  render();
  requestAnimationFrame(simulate); 

};

function render() {

  console.log("rendering" + sphere.position.z);
  renderer.render(scene,camera);
};

init();
simulate();`
```

Comment: Could you update this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/cN2J8/) to show your problem?

Comment: Thank you. Actually that fiddle doesn't work for me, I have tried the jsfiddle on another PC which works fine, so it must be my machine. I'm currently looking at browser/graphics setup to see if anything I can do. Thanks.

Comment: If you work out a reproducible error condition, it could be worthwhile to document it in an answer. This might help someone else at some point.

Comment: Hi, I now have this working on the same PC. I strongly suspect it was the version of Chromium (although I had to update some other bits to allow that to update). The version of Chromium that its now working fine on is 25.0.1364.160 (on Mint, with an Intel GM965/GL960 graphics chip). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved after an update of Chromium browser in this case (and possible related libs/drivers) to version 25.0.1346.160. Isolated by using jsfiddle as  shown above by Tomalak.